# Api documentation for Rspec?

Tags: rspec

Is there an API documentation for Rspec like the one for Rails?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd recommend the [RSpec Book](http://www.pragprog.com/titles/achbd/the-rspec-book). You can get a beta PDF version, as the actual book is not yet available at time of writing.

Granted, it covers BDD, Cucumber and others, but it's mainly about RSpec. The [official site](http://rspec.info/documentation/) had poor documentation to begin with, saying that, there's not much to RSpec. What I do know is from that book, and quick blog posts however.

Comment: To whoever downvoted this, this was true at time of writing. The documentation was weak. It has improved since.

Answer (score 9):

The official documentation for RSpec is hosted on relishapp
http://relishapp.com/rspec/

The documentation is quite good.

There's also pure API documentation which is a little less helpful.  It's hosted at
http://rubydoc.info/gems/rspec-core/2.6.4/RSpec

All of this documentation is pulled from the source code, so if you're curious to see the documentation mixed in with the code you can check out rspec from github.

Answer (score 1):

They have *some* documentation:
http://rspec.info/documentation/

It's not as good as Rails but it's a start.

Answer (score 1):

Also, some docs can be found here
 http://apidock.com/rspec